# corrupt database - copy all data except one table

Tags: sql-server

One of our dev databases is corrupt, the corruption exists in 1 table
I've used schemazen to create the blank database, and now I want to copy all data except 1 table

I've tried using the in build copy data from one to the other (both local on same server) but it keeps failing

Are there any other ways to copy the data / or entire database without this one table (free) ?
sql server 2017 developer edition.

Comment: "*I've tried using the in build copy data from one to the other (both local on same server) but it keeps failing*" - What tool are you referring to? What does "*keeps failing*" mean?...is it giving and error and what does that error say?

Comment: Have you tried just using the SSMS Import/Export Wizard?

Answer (score -1):

If you know which table is corrupted and there is no way to recover its data. Then you do not need to copy all data except the corrupted table.
You can just TRUCATE that table to fix the corruption.

BUT BEFORE TRUNCATE:

1. First: try to restore the corrupted page

2.Second: Try to copy all data of corrupted page except the rows located in corrupted page.

Comment: i've already copied out the data, and when i try and drop or truncate the table i get : Database ID 7, Page (4:2143320) is marked RestorePending, which may indicate disk corruption. To recover from this state, perform a restore.
 and i have to take DB offline and put online again to access it